# Capitalize each word except selected words in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, nlp

Right now I have

```
value = "United states of america"
words_to_ignore = ["the","of"]
new_string = value.split(' ').map {|w| w.capitalize }.join(' ')
```

What I am trying to do here is except the word `of`, I want the rest capitalized. So the output would be `United States of America`. Now I am not sure, how exactly to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
  new_string = value.split(' ')
    .each{|i| i.capitalize! if ! words_to_ignore.include? i }
    .join(' ')
```

Comment: @PrakamyaSharma `include` will return when it has value. So negating using `!`.

Comment: `i.capitalize! unless words_to_ignore.include? i` is the same

Comment: ok so unless there is a word matching ```words_to_ignore``` it will capitalize.

Comment: Also, no need to supply the space `(' ')` to the split method, it defaults to that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like:

```
value = "United state of america"
words_to_ignore = ["the","of"]
new_string = value.split(' ').map do |w| 
  unless words_to_ignore.include? w
    w.capitalize
  else
    w
  end
end
new_string[0].capitalize!
new_string = new_string.join(' ')
```

Comment: @PrakamyaSharma sorry try the new version. Thought `join!` should be present.

Comment: unfortunately this method doesnt capitalize the first if its present in the array. how do i fix that ?

Comment: I have added another line to fix that too.

Answer (score 1):

I propose using a hash to store the capitalization procedure and exceptions in one package:

```
value       = 'united states of america'
title_cases = Hash.new {|_,k| k.capitalize }.merge({'of' => 'of', 'off' => 'off'})
new_string  = value.split(" ").map {|w| title_cases[w] }.join(' ') #=> "United States of America"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
value = "United state of america"
words_to_ignore = Hash[%w[the of].map{|w| [w, w]}]
new_string = value.gsub(/\w+/){|w| words_to_ignore[w] || w.capitalize}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to force always the same result:

```
downcase_words = ["of", "the"]
your_string.split(' ').each{ |word| (downcase_words.include? word.downcase) ? 
                                     word.downcase! : word.capitalize! }.join(' ')
```

And your_string could be:

'united states of america'
'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA'
'uNitEd stAteS oF aMerIca'

And the result will always be: **"United States of America"**